# How to get FCM server key which is to be parsed in authorization header in php curl request?

Tags: php, android, push-notification, http-status-code-401, firebase-notifications

I tried with web api key which i got from > firebase console> My Project> project setting>General Tab.
NOTE : Currently I am not using paid developer account. I just create a new google account and created a project.

```
$url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
$server_key = '??????WHAT TO PUT HERE ????';
$fields = [];
$data = [];
$data['type'] = $type;
$data['title'] = $title;
$data['message'] = $message;
$data['sound'] = 'default';
$fields['data'] = $data;
if (is_array($id)) {
    $fields['registration_ids'] = $id; // array of registration ids
} else {
    $fields['to'] = $id; single registration id
}
//$fields['content_available'] = "true";
//header with content_type api key
$headers = array(
    'Content-Type:application/json',
    'Authorization:key=' . $server_key
);
$notification = array();
$notification['title'] = $title;
$notification['body'] = $message;
$notification['sound'] = 'default';
$notification['click_action'] = $type;
$fields['notification'] = $notification;

$fields = json_encode($fields);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $result;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click on `Setting` Icon on Right of `Overview` navigation option and select `Project Setting` from popup and select `cloud Messaging` tab you will see the `Server Key` and `Legacy Server Key`.

Comment: I dont  see legacy anymore

Answer (score 0):

As of 2023

Go to the firebase console. Select your project. Goto Project settings->Service accounts then scroll down to "Generate new private key". A json file will be downloaded with the details you need.